# Javascript Expiration Date Validate Status

Tags: javascript, validation, date, status

I have this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=x_contract]:radio').click(function(){
            var date = new Date($("#x_installeddate").val());
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Yearly"){
                var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 12, date.getDate());            
            } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "2 Years") {
                var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 24, date.getDate()); 
            } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "3 Years") {
                var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 36, date.getDate()); 
        }
        lastMonth = ( (lastDay.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' + (lastDay.getMonth() + 1) : (lastDay.getMonth() + 1);
        lastDate = ( lastDay.getDate() < 10 ) ? '0' + lastDay.getDate() : lastDay.getDate();
        var newDate =  lastDay.getFullYear() + '/' + lastMonth + '/' + lastDate;
        if (isNaN(lastMonth) == false) $("#x_expirationdate").val(newDate);
    });
});
```

This function generates an expiration date yearly, in 2 years and in 3 years. After this function generates the expiration date I want to have a status update wheter it is expired or not. This depends on the current date. If the date is expired I want the other column status in 1  and 0 if not.

How can I solve this in JavaScript :) ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, can you make a fiddle/example out of this please. Will make it easier for someone to try and solve this.

Comment: You have not tagged any libraries or frameworks, yet clearly some are being used. It is helpful if you do so.

Comment: *lastDay* is declared 3 times, *lastMonth* and *lastDay* aren't declared at all so become global when the code runs. When will `isNaN(lastMonth)` be true? What value does `$("#x_installeddate").val()` return?

Answer (score 0):

In the following code time-stamp is being compared between today's date and calculated last date to find whether the last date is expired or still valid.

I hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=x_contract]:radio').click(function(){
        var date = new Date($("#x_installeddate").val());
        var today = new Date(), todayTimeStamp = 0, lastDayTimeStamp = 0;

        if($(this).attr("value")=="Yearly"){
            var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 12, date.getDate());            
        } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "2 Years") {
            var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 24, date.getDate()); 
        } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "3 Years") {
            var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 36, date.getDate()); 
        }
        lastMonth = ( (lastDay.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' + (lastDay.getMonth() + 1) : (lastDay.getMonth() + 1);
        lastDate = ( lastDay.getDate() < 10 ) ? '0' + lastDay.getDate() : lastDay.getDate();
        var newDate =  lastDay.getFullYear() + '/' + lastMonth + '/' + lastDate;
        if (isNaN(lastMonth) == false) $("#x_expirationdate").val(newDate);

        todayTimeStamp = today.getTime();
        lastDayTimeStamp = lastDay.getTime();

        if(todayTimeStamp > lastDayTimeStamp) {
            // expired
            // status is 1
        } else {
            // Valid
            // status is 0
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: status is another column in database for example                                column: expiration date value : 2016-05-25 column: status  value:1

Comment: @Laj you can use an ajax call inside the `if` `else` loop to send the update to the back-end script(for eg: filename.php) to update the DB column as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more complex and inefficient than it needs to be. I assume that the return value from `$("#x_installeddate").val()` is being correctly parsed by *new Date*, which is problematic. There many questions here about parsing dates.

Anyway, if you want to generate a date based on the selected date, then compare it to today, consider the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=x_contract]:radio').click(function checkDate() {

    // Create a date for the selected date
    var date = new Date($("#x_installeddate").val());

    // Create a date for the selected period ahead from
    // the selected date    
    var values = {'Yearly':12, '2 Years':24, '3 Years':36};
    var lastDate = new Date(+date);
    lastDate.setMonth(lastDate.getMonth() + values[this.value]);

    // Create a string for lastDate
    var newDate = lastDate.getFullYear() + '/' +
                  ('0'+(lastDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
                  ('0'+lastDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

    // Get the current date and compare with lastDate
    var now = new Date();
    if (now < lastDate) {
      // lastDate is in the future
    } else {
      // lastDate is today or earlier
    }
  });
});
```

It would be much better if the values of the radio buttons where years so they return values like 1, 2 and 3 for 1, 2 and 3 years respectively. Then you can do:

```
lastDate.setMonth(lastDate.getMonth() + this.value*12);
```

and remove the *values* object.

The *date* variable is not reused, so it could be modified and used instead of *lastDate*.